# Is there a way to build vue.js components without using the npm server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component

Put simply, I want to use vue.js's [single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) inside of another project with *its own* web server and backend code. I want to "compile" my .vue files the way I would compile CoffeeScript files, or LESS files.

For example, suppose I have a Flask/Python project (which I do), in which I have my own web server that serves static files. I may layout my project like this:

`static/src/frontend.vue` -> `static/build/frontend.css`, `static/build/frontend.js`

I see that Vue's documentation has examples for running a node.js web server to generate built files live. What I don't see, however, is a way to simply compile the .vue files into another directory and exit. Is this possible with npm/webpack/node.js/vue.js?

Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any of the vuejs-templates for [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and simply run `npm run build``

Another alternative is [Jeffrey Way's vueify for laravel-elixir](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vue) which depends on gulp.

Comment: These days Laravel Mix is probably the way to go (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix)